# Почему не работает проверка на равенство элементов в двух массивах в цикле?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задача:
Функция принимает 2 массива и возвращает новый массив. В новом массиве собраны все элементы из первого массива, которых нет во втором массиве.
Написал таким образом:

```
let arr, arrSmall;
arr = [];
arrSmall = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    arr[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
}
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    arrSmall[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
}
firstNoSecond = () => {
    let arrFirstNoSecond;
    arrFirstNoSecond = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        Large: {
            for (j = 0; j < arrSmall.length; ++j) {
                Small: {
                    if (arr[i] === arrSmall[j]) {
                        break Large;
                    }
                    else {
                        arrFirstNoSecond[i] = arr[i];
                        break Small;
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }
    console.log(`Элементы первого, которых нет во втором - ${arrFirstNoSecond}`);
    console.log(arrFirstNoSecond.length);
}
```

Не работает - всегда возвращает длину массива 10 и не удаляет совпадающие элементы.
В чем причина?

Comment: метки неверно расставлены и добавление в массив неверное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код чрезмерно усложнен и запутан. Основная ошибка в том, что в конструкции

```
Small: {
        if (arr[i] === arrSmall[j]) {
            break Large;
        }
        else {
            arrFirstNoSecond[i] = arr[i];
            break Small;
        }
       }
```

вы игнорируете одинаковые числа только в том случае, если эти числа - первые по порядку во втором массиве. В ином случае вы просто не доходите до проверки такого числа, поскольку сразу заносите его в результирующий массив и прерываете цикл.

Вообще удобнее без явных циклов делать.

```js
const generate = (n) => Array.from({length: n}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
const arr = generate(10), arrSmall = generate(5)
const out = arr.filter(x => !arrSmall.includes(x))
console.log(`Первый массив: ${arr}\nВторой массив: ${arrSmall}\nРезультат:     ${out}`)
```

С циклами

```js
generate = (n, range) => {
    const out = []
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
        out.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * range))
    return out
}

const arr = generate(10, 10), arrSmall = generate(5, 10);
console.log(`Первый = [${arr}]`);
console.log(`Второй = [${arrSmall}]`);

firstNoSecond = () => {
    const arrFirstNoSecond = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        Large:{
            for (let j = 0; j < arrSmall.length; ++j) {
                if (arr[i] === arrSmall[j])
                    break Large;
            }
            arrFirstNoSecond.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(`Элементы первого, которых нет во втором - [${arrFirstNoSecond}], длина = ${arrFirstNoSecond.length}`);
}

firstNoSecond()
```

Comment: плохой пример, слишком маленькая вероятность пересечения

Comment: Да то-то и  оно что решил без методов Array делать

Comment: @Павел, работать с массивами без методов массивов - невозможно